# Automatizing cursor movement in normal mode

Tags: cursor-movement, normal-mode

Beginner Vim user here.

I already learned about automating deleting with commands, which happens this way:

`[number]d[j/k/h/l] [OR] d[number][j/k/h/l]`

Where `number` stands for the amount of the action repeated.

- Can I use it for simply moving the cursor? Like `5l` - or `3w` to jump words.
- Is it good practice at all? Or can/should I find better ways of automatic cursor movement in Vim?

Comment: `Can I use it for simply moving the cursor? Like 5l - or 3w to jump words.` If you try it you'll see that `5l` and `3w` and `Xany motion` works :) `Is it a good practice? ` Whatever floats your boat... But a good practice is to use the right motion for the right destination: if you want to go far, use `/`, `? `, `n` or `N`, to the beginning or end of line: `0`, `^` ,  `$` just some words back and forth `w`, `b`, `e`, `ge` or even `f`, `F`, `t`, `T`, `;`,  `,` (I'm pretty sure there is a question here about that but I can't find it). `automatic cursor movement` what do you mean by `automatic`?

Comment: Finally Finally [`:h motion.txt`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#motion.txt) should be a good read for you, especially [`:h left-right-motions`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#left%2Dright%2Dmotions) and [`:h up-down-motions`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#up%2Ddown%2Dmotions)

Comment: @statox thank you very much! By "automatic" I meant exactly what you described.

Comment: I didn't see 'in command mode' in the title of your question... Thus my comment might be really off topic. Are you talking about motions to edit a command after you typed `:` or are you talking about navigation in the buffer in normal mode?

Comment: @statox - command mode *is* normal mode, what you're thinking is probably command-line mode. I.e. you're not off topic :P

Comment: @VanLaser Oh damn you're right I'm not fully awake today :D

Comment: @statox my mistake, I was confusing modes, I'm sorry.

Comment: @ZoltánSchmidt Actually you were not :-) [`:h command-mode`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/intro.txt.html#command%2Dmode) and [`:h Normal-mode`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/intro.txt.html#Normal%2Dmode) are the same topic the mode simply has two names that's why I was confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reword my comment:

> Can I use it for simply moving the cursor? Like `5l` - or `3w` to jump words.

Yes. Every motion command can be prefixed by a count.

> Is it good practice at all?

There can be exceptions/personal preferences mitigating what will follow but the general rule is to use the motion corresponding to the amplitude of the move you want to make.

Vim has an *enormous* amount of motion commands which allows you to travel in your buffer at different speeds: you can have motions to go from the beginning of the buffer to the end or from one character to the next one. I will not make an explicit list here because it's a lot of work and this work has already been done very well in [`:h motion.txt`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#motion.txt). Still here are some common example:

For up-down motions:

- Search commands allow you to travel your buffer pretty fast: `/` and `?` allow you to search for occurrences of a pattern and `n` and `N` repeat this search forward or backward
- Absolute commands like `gg`, `G`, `[count]G` allows you to move to first line, last line or line `[count]` in your buffer. So does `:[count]`
- For large up-down motions marks (like `'a` or `''`) can also be used and `%` is useful to go to the matching character (like matching `)` when cursor is on `(`)
- Text objects can also be used for that: use `{` and `}` to switch to the beginning or end of a paragraph.

For motions within a line you also have a lot of options:

- Go to beginning, first character or end of the line with `0`,  `^` and `$`
- Target a character with `f` or `t` and backward with `F` and `T`. Repeat these motions with `;` or `,`
- Move word wise with `b`, `w`, `e`, `ge`
- Move from one character to another with `h` and `l`. *(Yeah I do recommend to use `h` and `l`. See my note at the end)

I think that it is important to make a note about `h`, `j`, `k` and `l`:

Some Vimmers will tell you to never use them because it's slow and repetitive and yada yada... The whole point of Vim is to use the available motions **efficiently** if you need to move 3 words forward yeah that's not a good idea to press 20 times on `l` when you could use `3w`. **But** when you need a precise motion of two or three letter `h` and `l` are the way to go, just like `j` and `k` for moving two or three lines up or down.

That's why I believe that plugins like [vim hardmode](https://github.com/wikitopian/hardmode) are <s>stupid</s> not the correct solution to a problem which might not even exist.

In conclusion read [`:h motion.txt`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#motion.txt), grok it, get used to the motions commands one by one. When you use a motion which feel inefficient, go read the page again and find the correct motion to use.

As I often did on this site I'd also recommend to read the amazing [practical vim by Drew Neil](https://pragprog.com/book/dnvim/practical-vim) which has a very good chapter on motions. And [vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) probably also has a good reference about that (I'll let you find it ;-) )